# Apache FTP embedded server throws exception on shutdown

Tags: apache, ftp

When I shutdown my embedded FTP server (using the `stop()` method) I get the exception below.

Is there a way I can avoid this and shut down cleanly?

> 15:06:35.054 [pool-7-thread-2] | ERROR
>   o.a.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpHandler - Exception caught, closing
>   session java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpHandlerAdapter.inputClosed(Lorg/apache/mina/core/session/IoSession;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:834)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:611)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:938)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:134)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:611)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:938)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:134)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:611)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:938)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:134)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:611)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:938)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:134)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:611)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:938)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:134)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:611)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.inputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:938)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.inputClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:134)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:611)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireInputClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:604)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:729)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:668)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:657)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1121)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
>   ~[mina-core-2.0.8.jar:na]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_67]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_67]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Apache mina 2.0.7. In version 2.0.8 they added a new method in interface IoHandler but the ftpserver class FtpHandlerAdapter doesn't implement it.